# Multithreading program producing different ouptut

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm running a multi threaded program and the problem I have is that it produces different output each time it's run. Here's my code.

```
package com.mypackage;

public class TryThreads extends Thread{

    int i=-10;
    public static void main(String arg[]){
        TryThreads tt1=new TryThreads();
        TryThreads tt2=new TryThreads();
        tt1.start();
        tt2.start();

    }
    public synchronized void run() {
        for(;i<=10;i++) {
            System.out.println(TryThreads.getThreadName()+"  "+i);
        }
    }
    static String getThreadName() {
        Thread t1=new Thread();
        return t1.getName();
    }
}
```

whenever I run the code it produces different output, can anybody help me out with this?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7659615/why-synchronized-method-allowing-multiple-thread-to-run-concurrently

Comment: Why would you expect it to produce the same result every time? If you had two roughly-equivalent runners in an athletics race, would you expect the same result in every race?

Comment: What is the different output you get?

Comment: Why do you create a new `Thread` every time in `getThreadName()`?

Comment: "can anybody help me out with this?"  With what?  You haven't said what the problem is.  You did say that the program produces different output every time, but is that a problem?  Why is it a problem?  The best SO questions include a runnable code example, a description of what you expected to see, and an example of what you actually did see.

Answer (score 1):

**Let's sum up you code:**

1. You are starting two threads.
2. Your threads loop from i = -10 to 10
3. Each loop calls a static method.
4. The static method creates a NEW thread each time and returns the
   name of the NEW thread.
5. The caller thread outputs the name of each NEW thread plus the index
   variable i.

When you are running your code you are going to create 2 + 42 Threads (index 0 to 43).

First thing that makes no sense is that you are synchronizing the run() method which is useless because both of the two threads are working on their own object. The different output is as expected because you cannot predict when one of the two threads is active and iterating over the static getThreadName() method. It could be that Thread1 is doing 3 iterations before Thread2 is doing one. But it could also be that Thread2 is doing five iterations before Thread1 makes one.

This behaviour is called race confitions. It is up to the VM/OS to handle the threads if you don't manage them in you application code.

Answer (score 0):

It is normal but if you do:

```
public static void main(String arg[]){
    TryThreads tt1=new TryThreads();
    TryThreads tt2=new TryThreads();
    tt1.start();
    tt2.start();
    tt1.join();
    tt2.join();

}
```

Then you should get first thread 1 name and then thread 2 name. It is normal that you get different results. Usually you store thread results in for example different class variable making sure that everything is thread safe. For example making method that is writing data to some variable synchronized. There is many ways to do it. But in your case you get that result cause you do not join threads to the main thread. It would be more noticeable if you spawn more threads doing much more than printing thread name.

Here is nice article about threads -> [THREADS](http://www.journaldev.com/1061/java-synchronization-and-thread-safety-tutorial-with-examples)

But if you actually ask why your threads name are different then it is normal they are generated when you create new thread...

Comment: Adding the join() calls only causes the main thread to wait for the two spawned threads die before main itself dies.  How can that affect the output?  The output does not come from the main thread.